# Ember.js 1.2.0 debounce not working as expected on jquery events

Tags: jquery, ember.js, debouncing

I am trying to set up a debounce on the window's resize event and have previously been able to with underscore and jquery as follows:

```
$(window).on('resize', _.debounce($.proxy(this.windowWidthChanged, this), 333));
```

I took this thinking and tried to apply it to Ember's `Ember.run.debounce` as follows:

```
$(window).on('resize', Ember.run.debounce(this, this.windowWidthChanged, 333));
```

The event listener does not seem to fire at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like you might have guessed, you weren't passing a function into the resize event, but the cancel information(the result of calling debounce).

```
var self = this;
$(window).on('resize', function(){ Ember.run.debounce(self, self.windowWidthChanged, 333)});
```

This goes back to the classic setTimeout dilemma, why is it running immediately?

```
setTimeout(alert('hello'),2000)
```

Comment: thanks -- anyone reading this for future reference, as of ember 1.4 you can use `Ember.run.bind` which acts like `$.proxy`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up wrapping it in an anonymous function inside a proxy to maintain `this` context:

```
$(window).on('resize', $.proxy(function() {
    Ember.run.debounce(this, this.windowWidthChanged, 333);
}, this));
```

I suppose you could just move the `Ember.run.debounce` inside `windowWidthChanged` as well.